# Why is read acting differently in bash and dash?

Tags: bash, shell, dash-shell, built-in

This is an attempt to find out how is the read utility working in several shells. Found a difference that seems like a bug to me.

Results are that dash retains trailing spaces with read:

```
dash: <a b     >
bash: <a b>
```

In short: Why this code perform differently in bash and dash read?

```
dash -c 'echo "    a b     " | { read var; echo "<$var>"; }'
bash -c 'echo "    a b     " | { read var; echo "<$var>"; }'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an easier way of demonstrating your issue:

```
$ dash -c 'echo "a b     " | { read var; echo "<$var>"; }'
<a b     >
$ bash -c 'echo "a b     " | { read var; echo "<$var>"; }'
<a b>
```

This only happens when there are two or more fields, like `"a b   "`, and not when there is just one, like `"a   "`.

Here's [what POSIX says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html) (emphasis mine):

> If there are fewer vars than fields, the last var shall be set to a value comprising the following elements:
>
> - The field that corresponds to the last var in the normal assignment sequence described above
> - The delimiter(s) that follow the field corresponding to the last var
> - The remaining fields and their delimiters, **with trailing IFS white space ignored**

`dash` does not ignore the trailing IFS white space, so it appears to be in violation of POSIX.

The `bash` behavior is correct.